# Adjust margins for BibTeX using LyX

Tags: bibtex, lyx, margins, geometry

I'm working on my thesis. Most of the new chapters etc start with a 2" margin on the first page. However, the Bibliography is supposed to start with an 1" margin. I left the document's default margins as 1" since each new chapter sets the first page as 2" anyway, but the 1" default is ignored by BibTeX. I am using the report class. Any ideas on how I can adjust it?

```
% Preview source code from paragraph 0 to 13

\begin{singlespace}

\chapter*{\textmd{\large Drudge: A High-Level to High-Level Translator for
the EasyC Platform}}
\end{singlespace}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
Brandon Paul Jones
\par\end{center}

\begin{center}
\vspace{4sp}

\par\end{center}

\begin{center}
A Thesis presented to the faculty of Arkansas State University in
partial fulfillment of the requirements for the Degree of
\par\end{center}

\begin{center}
\vspace{2sp}
MASTER OF SCIENCE IN COMPUTER SCIENCE\\
\vspace{0.25in}

\par\end{center}

\begin{center}
ARKANSAS STATE UNIVERSITY\\
December 2012
\par\end{center}

\begin{center}
\vspace{2in}

\par\end{center}

\begin{singlespace}
\begin{center}
Approved by\\
Dr. Jeff Jenness, Thesis Advisor\\
Dr. Hai Jiang, Committee Member\\
Dr. Hung-Chi Su, Committee Member\\
Mr. Jake Qualls, Committee Member\pagebreak{}
\par\end{center}
\end{singlespace}


\chapter*{\textmd{\large ABSTRACT}}

\begin{doublespace}
\begin{center}
{\large Brandon Paul Jones}\linebreak{}

\par\end{center}{\large \par}

\begin{center}
{\large Drudge: A High-Level to High-Level Translator for the EasyC
Platform}{\Large }\linebreak{}

\par\end{center}{\Large \par}
\end{doublespace}

The use of abstraction along with the use of critical thinking are
key concepts in computer science. The development of these skills
are crucial for survival and success in the field. I believe the key
to success is to allow students to experiment with computer science
concepts at an early age. The BEST robotics competition is a fertile
ground for potential future computer scientists and engineers, however
the current robotic programming platforms prove to be overly challenging
for the young audience. In this thesis, I propose both a new approach
to teaching younger individuals programming, as well as, a new platform
in which to do so.\pagebreak{}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{proposal}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about LyX, but you can use the `geometry` package and then use

```
\newgeometry{left=1in,right=1in}
```

just before the bibliography

Comment: I tried `\newgeometry{top=1in}` but it didn't do anything

Comment: @Pinsickle I think we need [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to understand what's going on.

Comment: I added it to my original post. The version up there is after I removed the call to `\newgeometry`. That was pulled from the "view source" option of LyX so let me know if you need something else.